# Can Quartz .Net handle a long running job in background in a MVC app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

I am wondering if it is appropriate to use Quartz .NET for a long running task, which would last up to a few hours for a MVC app. I understand that it is not safe to use Task or Thread to perform the job because of IIS pool recycling, and Hangfire could do the job. But since I am already using quartz, it is easier to just stick with one framework instead of using another.

Comment: I don't see why not. I use it. But be aware of the separation of concerns. One thing is the scheduling that just starts the task, and another thing is the task itself.

Comment: What prevents you from running a separate service to do the processing? That's far more ideal: running a long job directly in your website should only be a very last resort.

Comment: @mason I have no control over the server and I am not familiar with window service or web service.

Comment: @PedroSouki my question is specifically regarding to the long running task. Since Quartz triggers it, I am not sure if it provides some sort of mechanism that prevents iis from killing the task.

Comment: A Windows service is merely console application that's been registered to run as a service with Windows. This whole practice is made considerably easier if you use a library such as [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/). Services (or some hosted solution such as Azure Web Jobs) are the best way to do handle long running jobs. IIS websites normally shut down after a period of inactivity: any background job will be terminated at that point, even it's running in Quartz or Hangfire. It also uses up valuable threads that are better used by your web application.

Comment: I agree with @mason. The Quartz responsability is the scheduling. When I mentioned the separation of concerns I meant what mason said. I suggest to you to run these task in a windows service or Azure Web Jobs.